# String isn't printed after using strcpy

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy string `s` to `r` using `strcpy()`. But it does not print out any result. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char s[] = "john lemon";
    char r[] = "";
    strcpy(s, r);
    cout<<s<<"   "<<r;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that unless you are trying to learn C (in which case you should probably use C and not C++), "legacy" "C-style" arrays and strings are a very advanced topic. You should first learn `std::string` and other C++ stuff, before going low-level (manual resource management, worrying about buffer overflows, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcpy(a,b)` copies the string `b` into the string `a`

You have copied the empty string to the the string `s`. After the copy it also contains the empty string.

Printing empty string results with no characters outputted as empty string does not contain any printable ones.

If you want to copy in the opposite direction you must make sure that the destination array has enough elements to accommodate the source string.

```
char s[] = "john lemon";
char r[sizeof(s)] = "";
strcpy(r, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `strcpy(char* dest, char* src)` is the destination string where the content is to be copied, while the second one is the source string to be copied. Be aware that it is important to reserve enough space for the parameter `dest` to receive the content.

So try this please:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char s[] = "john lemon";
    char r[20];
    strcpy(r, s);
    cout<<s<<"   "<<r;
    return 0;
}
```